# How to test different app configurations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, testing, automated-tests, functional-testing

In our ASP.NET MVC 3 app we have few settings which changes behaviour of few pages.  We want to run functional tests for each configuration.  That is, we have large set of common tests and some tests that unique for particular configuration.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What testing framework, and when you say "pages" do you mean testing the views, or controllers/actions?

Comment: We use NUnit for run tests and Watin for browsing.  When I say "page" I mean bundle of controller, view and all static content (images, scripts) which forms page.  Functional tests for this page will simulate user activity on this page.